# jQuery to click "data-post_id"

Tags: jquery

So, I have a anchor link and a button.

The anchor is dynamically generated as below:

```
 echo <a href="#something_else" class="my_class" data-post_id="' . esc_attr( $post->id ) . '" >' . Title . '</a>';
```

As you can see, the anchor gets `data-post_id` from `$post->id`.

I have a simple button.

```
<button class="my_button" pro type="button">
    <?php echo $post->title(); ?>
</button >
```

I am trying to make it so that when the button is clicked, the anchor is also clicked based on the `data-post_id`.

For example, there are 5 posts and 5 buttons automatically generated based on the `data-post_id`.

When a button is clicked, then based on its `data-post_id`, I want to trigger click event on the corresponding anchor with the same `data-post_id`.

Is there a jquery or other simpler way of doing it?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you set the `post_id` with `button`?

Comment: yes, you can use `.trigger()`

Comment: How're you linking the anchors and the buttons? How're they positioned? Can you show the full HTML for anchors and buttons.

Comment: Give us the rendered HTML code please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set he `data-post_id`  to the button, then when it is clicked find anchor tag using it. After that you can fire click event using **[`click()`](https://api.jquery.com/click/)** or **[`trigger('click')`](https://api.jquery.com/trigger/)**

**PHP:**

```
<button class="my_button" pro type="button" data-post_id="' . esc_attr( $post->id ) . '">
    <?php echo $post->title(); ?>
</button >
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('button').click(function(){
   $("a[data-post_id='" + $(this).data("post_id") + "']").click();
});
```

Comment: Thank you. Exactly what I needed  =)

Comment: @EmilyTurcato : glad to help